# CSS Image Rollovers

Tags: html, css, rollovers

```
<div id="navigation>
    <ul class="navlist">
        <li><img src="images/btn1.gif"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/btn2.gif"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/btn3.gif"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How would I be able to give these "buttons" within the list rollover states without using JS? I'm totally drawing a blank...

These links must be images.

Comment: You forgot to close the quote in your DIV id: id="navigation <==

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're supporting newer browsers (browsers that support the `:hover` selector on all elements, which is basically everything except IE6, see [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)) you can do this with CSS provided you change your HTML. You will need to remove the `img` tags, and instead use background images.

CSS (this is the simple example with 2 images, you'll need to set the height + width. If you have many different images, you'll need a css class for each of them):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .navlist li { width: 32px; height: 32px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url('images/image1.gif'); }
    .navlist li:hover { background-image: url('images/image2.gif'); }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul class="navlist">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So if I wanted to make sure that IE6 works as well, what would be your recommended solution?

Comment: I would say use `a` tags and set the background image on that element, because IE6 supports `:hover` on `a` tags. Otherwise, you're stuck using Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of ways to do this. Basically, move one image off the screen when you hover. Or you could change the z-index of two images on top of each other when you hover, or you could do it with background images, or with the display option.

I prefer using the display option, since the CSS is quite simpple.

Since it's done with classes you can just add as many buttons as you want.

Here's the code for a page that contains the HTML and CSS together.
**The DOCTYPE declaration is necessary to make it work in IE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/\xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            a img {
                border:none;
            }
            ul {
                list-style-type: none;
            }
            img.defaultSt {
                display: inline;
            }
            img.hoverSt {
                display: none;
            }
            li:hover img.defaultSt {
                display: none;
            }
            li:hover img.hoverSt {
                display: inline;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul class="navlist">
                <li>
                    <img class="defaultSt" src="http://mrg.bz/vh60HV" />
                    <img class="hoverSt" src="http://mrg.bz/CcDOmL" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: With regards to SEO and background images, having text inside the element containing the background works well. Simply use `margin-left: -99em` on the text to effectively hide it (or `font-size: 0`, but I'm not sure if that works in all browsers).

Comment: @Paperjam, yeah, I actually just decided that the margin solution is ugly, and "display" is cleaner...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a transparent image as the link primary and then use css to alter the background

```
<style type="text/css">
    a.img1, a.img1:link { background-image: url(images/btn1.gif); }
    a.img1:hover { background-image: url(images/btn1_over.gif); }

    a.img2, a.img2:link { background-image: url(images/btn2.gif); }
    a.img2:hover { background-image: url(images/btn2_over.gif); }

    a.img3, a.img3:link { background-image: url(images/btn3.gif); }
    a.img3:hover { background-image: url(images/btn3_over.gif); }
</style>

<div id="navigation>
    <ul class="navlist">
        <li><a class="img1" href=""><img src="images/transparent_image.gif" width="x" height="y"/></a></li>
        <li><a class="img2" href=""><img src="images/transparent_image.gif" width="x" height="y"/></a></li>
        <li><a class="img3" href=""><img src="images/transparent_image.gif" width="x" height="y"/></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You just have to keep in mind the size of the images in question.